# How to use Kafka consumer in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using spark 2.1 and Kafka 0.10.1.

I want to process the data by reading the entire data of specific topics in Kafka on a daily basis.

For spark streaming, I know that `createDirectStream` only needs to include a list of topics and some configuration information as arguments.

However, I realized that `createRDD` would have to include all of the topic, partitions, and offset information.

I want to make batch processing as convenient as streaming in spark.

Is it possible?

Comment: did u happen to get answer to your question?

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to read this text from [Cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/exactly-once-spark-streaming-from-apache-kafka/).

This example show you how to get from Kafka the data just one time. That you will persist the offsets in a postgres due to the ACID archtecture.

So I hope that will solve your problem.